# Is Redux thunk synchronous?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

My understanding of Redux Thunk is that it becomes async only if we execute some async code (like api calls), otherwise it remains synchronous.

```
    import { createAction } from "redux-action";
    export const updateStore = createAction("UPDATE_STORE") //action to update redux store        
    export const firstAction = () => {
         return dispatch => {
              dispatch(secondAction())
              dispatch(thirdAction())
         }
    }
    export const secondAction = () => {
         return dispatch => {
              dispatch(updateStore()) //update the redux store
              dispatch(actionAfterStoreUpdate()) // execute after redux store is updated
         }
    }
```

Here's what I expect the order to be:

1. **firstAction** starts executing
2. **secondAction** starts executing
3. **updateStore** is finished
4. **actionAfterStoreUpdate** is finished
5. **secondAction** is finished
6. **thirdAction** is finished
7. **firstAction** is finished

I am not getting the exact above order, as **actionAfterStoreUpdate** is getting executed before **updateStore**.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my understanding? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what's `updateStore` in this example?

Comment: @njzk2 It is a redux action of type "UPDATE_STORE", which will update the store. I am using helper function createAction() to create this action as given here:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction

Comment: How are you determining in which order those are executed and what is your definition of "executed"?

Comment: @phry I am determining by the order in which they are called () top to bottom and by execution I think function going on the call stack doing its task  and then finally popping out of it.

Comment: no, not how are you assuming it, but how are you determining what is actually happening? how do you observe that? Because assuming all your actions are synchronous, your assumptions are correct, so I think you're "measuring" wrong.